# Why isn't a replacement light fixture working?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

Lots of wires here. About 6 yrs ago I replaced an old ceiling fan with an LED ceiling light. All was working fine (though we did have honeybees try to escape through this light after making a hive inside the walls, but that's another story).

Two days ago I flipped the switch "on", and *poof* a small flash of light at the LED light and it stopped working. However - the breaker **didn't trip** (200amp service, upgraded last summer).

I swapped the light with the exact same type of light, and exact same wiring, flipped the switch "on", and it still doesn't work. **Breaker still didn't trip.**

I tested with a pen meter at the switch itself, and all wires have voltage. I tried to unravel this mess of wires at the light, and tested each wire cap, and here's what I found:

- All wiring **going to the light** is dead, all the time. Includes white and black wires.
- All wiring **away from the light EXCEPT for one wire cap** (whether as junctions for other switches further down the line) is hot, all the time. Includes the old red fan wire (currently capped and unused).
- There is **one set of wires with a black piece of tape on it** that is hot **only when the switch is on**. Why this was not used previously as the hot wire to the light is a mystery to me.

**Below is the current wiring situation:**
[image: current wiring situation]

So I'm wondering: should I rewire the white wire to the light to utilize the line that is **hot when the switch is "on"**? And keep the current black wire as it is? Or is this a bad idea?

**What I'm proposing:**
[image: what I'm proposing - good or bad idea?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, what you are proposing is exactly the wrong way to rewire the light.

The white wire from the light is the Neutral and should be kept together with the other "always dead" whites.

If you want to re-wire, you could connect the black wire from the light to the wire-nut that is only hot when the switch is on.

But I would recommend that you first try to trace which wire goes where and why those blacks in the left of your picture are always dead.